# Buying in-game currency but not receiving what you pay for with the in-game currency

Tags: united-states, currency

I am in a somewhat debate with a friend regarding in-game currency.

TLDR: I told him I could have a case if the game I bought in-game currency for would provide the in-game currency, but when I buy a product with the in-game currency, I do not get what I 'paid' for.

***Complete story:***

Me and my friend used to play a video game in which you could buy in-game currency with real money.

Last time when I checked however, I found out the game had a couple of issues regarding the in-game currency. Think of: You buying a product with a time-limit usage to get exclusive content (if you would use the product in a certain amount of time), only to experience down-time etc. and preventing you from using the product to the fullest extend. The game does explicitly say you will not 'own' any goods, but rather will 'unlock' the goods.

Could you either demand a compensation or demand a chargeback? (think of either receiving your real money or the in-game currency again).

My friend his point of view was: You have nothing to back yourself up with, because you got the in-game currency when you paid money and that is considered the product you 'paid' for.

I found this article on here [Charging someone with theft of virtual currency](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/36785/charging-someone-with-theft-of-virtual-currency) but it didn't make me much wiser.

I am talking about general US law.